# A better than O(N) solution for searching a vector of sorted intervals

Tags: c++, search, vector

Given a set of sorted intervals (first >= second), sorted by the first element of the interval:

```
{1, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {3, 3}, {3, 7}
```

is there an efficient algorithm for determining the first interval that intersects a given
input interval?  For example:

```
Query ({0, 0}) = returns end()
Query ({2, 4}) = returns iterator to element 0
Query ({3, 8}) = returns iterator to element 0
Query ({4, 9}) = returns iterator to element 2
Query ({7, 8}) = returns iterator to element 7
Query ({8, 9}) = returns end()
```

By efficient I mean better than O(N).  I have a vague feeling there's a *lower_bound* or *upper_bound* solution to this problem but I don't have the mental horsepower to work out what it is.

This is the O(N) solution that I'm unsatisfied with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using Interval = std::pair<int, int>;
    using Sequence = std::vector<Interval>;
    using Iterator = Sequence::const_iterator;

    auto Query = [](Sequence const & sequence, Interval const & interval) -> Iterator
    {
        return std::find_if(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), [interval](Interval const & other) {
            return interval.first <= other.second && interval.second >= other.first;
        });
    };

    auto Print = [](Sequence const & sequence, Iterator const & iterator) -> void
    {
        if (iterator == sequence.cend())
        {
            std::cout << "end()\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << std::to_string(std::distance(sequence.cbegin(), iterator)) << "\n";
        }
    };

    Sequence sequence = {
        {1, 3}, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 4 }, { 2, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 5 }, { 3, 3 }, { 3, 7 }
    };

    auto result = Iterator();

    result = Query(sequence, { 0, 0 });

    Print(sequence, result);

    result = Query(sequence, { 2, 4 });

    Print(sequence, result);

    result = Query(sequence, { 3, 8 });

    Print(sequence, result);

    result = Query(sequence, { 4, 9 });

    Print(sequence, result);

    result = Query(sequence, { 7, 8 });

    Print(sequence, result);

    result = Query(sequence, { 8, 9 });

    Print(sequence, result);
}
```

Output:

```
end()
0
0
2
7
end()
```

Comment: Are you bound to store the data this way, or is this something you came up with so far but willing to change? I'm asking b/c there's a better data structure for this I think...

Comment: You cannot afford to skip any interval whose left bound is lower than the right bound of your requested interval, as the right bound (over which there's no sort/constraint) can always assume a value that may make the examined interval intersect, so you cannot jump immediately to an "interesting zone" using binary search. The only improvement you can have with this data layout is to have an early exit when the examined interval left bound gets greater than the requested interval right bound.

Comment: If the list is sorted, then a binary search works well, which is `O(logN)`.  That said, how big of a data set are you dealing with?  A `O(N)` traversal over a `std::vector` is hard to beat considering processors are designed to love contiguous data.

Comment: At the moment I've got the intervals in an array.  However if you think a different structure would make the problem easier, I'm willing to do that.  The actual use case involves times (uint64_t), not integers.  i.e. periods of time intersecting other periods of time.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think you can do binary search. The vector is sorted by _left_ points of the intervals; the right points can be arbitrary.

Comment: I've set the data set size reasonable worst case to about 5 million intervals, and I'll be doing around 100 queries against it per "frame" (at around 20 fps).

Comment: @Robinson Do this (I suggest): build a tree. When you insert an interval, you insert both coordinates separately and each node stores whether it's left or right (i.e., to-the-right covered or to-the-left covered). You can even do the standard rotations on this tree to keep it balanced. Then you can query the tree by the interval.

Comment: Do you care about what specific interval intersects, or you just care about the fact that there's an intersection? Are these intervals relatively fixed (compared to the number of queries) or always changing?

Comment: @NathanOliver The only thing a binary search can determine is where in the vector you can end the search, because every following value will start at a value too large for the desired value to be found there. I think you still need to perform a linear search in that range, and if you do that, you will find this early end value anyway, you don't need to search for it first.

Comment: So let me clarify that.  For this query I don't care about the specific intervals, I just care to know if there is one.  Later on I will ask for the specific set of intersecting intervals, however that can be done in "user time" (UI response time), which is a few seconds not a few ms, so a slower solution is fine for that.  The number of intervals grows over time.

Comment: If you only want to find if *any* interval in the range intersects the interval you're looking for, rather than the first such instance in the range, please edit the question to say that explicitly.

Comment: I found something called an "interval tree"... I wonder if that's what Lorro meant... https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/public_user/JamesStewart/378notes/22intervals/

Comment: @Robinson Exactly.

Comment: In this case, the solution is easy: merge the overlapping intervals (single pass on the sorted array, O(n)); this will result in a sequence of intervals where not only the left bounds are growing, but where you always have the i-th right bound less than the i+1-th left bound. This is amenable to a binary search to find just the intervals that have to be examined for your query. If you put all the bounds sorted in a single integer array you can do some neat tricks checking if the found index is odd or even.

Comment: There may be five million intervals, none of which overlap, e.g. {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 10}, {20, 22}, etc.  I'm thinking I need an interval tree impl actually...

Comment: Lorro can I ask you to add that as an answer please?  Though perhaps if the question is not useful and that answer was obvious, maybe I should delete the question.

Comment: @Robinson if they do not overlap it's fine, in that case the merge pass will be a no-op. The lookup will still be a binary search. Do a `upper_bound` for the left bound: if the found index is odd, the you have a match (the left bound is inside an interval). Otherwise, the left bound is outside, and the element you found is the start of the next interval. If it's less than your right bound, then you have a match, otherwise your interval is in a hole between two intervals and thus it doesn't have any intersection.

Comment: I recommend asking a new question. The posted question is answered and shouldn't be modified anymore in a way it would invalidate the given answer. But according to the comments, it seems like the posted question isn't the actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There cannot be a faster than linear algorithm. Consider the input where the first value of each element is 0 and the second value is random uniform over some range. Consider the query to be `{x,x+1}` where `x` is in the same range.

Since you want "the first interval that intersects a given input", the sorting is now useless. You must scan it all.

Hence, you cannot beat `O(N)`.

Comment: Technically, this is the answer - however, in comments OP wrote they're open to changing the data structure of input (which allows faster).

Comment: If the input is sorted by the start and then the end you could still find the interval faster for this case. But if the input is `{i, x - 1}` for `i in [0, x - 1(` then you have to scan every input.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer.  The final solution for me was to use a vector of hashes of arrays.  Yes I know it sounds dumb but it works nicely for my specific use case.  I'm able to query against four million intervals in under a ms.  All the effort goes into constructing the structure.  Query is fast.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, with the data structure outlined in the question you cannot do better than linear

> You cannot afford to skip any interval whose left bound is lower than the right bound of your requested interval, as the right bound (over which there's no sort/constraint) can always assume a value that may make the examined interval intersect, so you cannot jump immediately to an "interesting zone" using binary search.

although you can have an early exit once you reach the interval whose left bound is greater than the query's right bound.

However, given that OP is ok with changing the data representation, this can be made much easier once you make the intervals non-overlapping; given that we are only interested in an intersects/doesn't intersect test, it's not much of a problem.

Starting with the sorted data, merging overlapping intervals is just a matter of a single linear pass to do once: keep a "current" element, and keep it growing as long as you read overlapping elements; once you get a disjoint one, push the "current" one and make this the new "current". This can be also easily be made to work inplace, as a variant of the usual `remove_if` algorithm.

Once you have sorted disjoint intervals, you can apply binary search to your problem to have O(log n) queries. Instead of a `vector<pair>` a more advantageous structure is a plain `vector<int>` with the (sorted) bounds flattened into a single sequence.

With this representation, a query goes like this:

- do a `upper_bound` looking for the left bound of the query interval;
- if you get `end`, then no bound is greater, so we have no intersection;
- otherwise, get the index from the iterator:

  - if the index is odd, it means that the first bound greater than the searched value is a *right* bound; that means that the query left bound falls inside an interval, thus we have an intersection;
  - otherwise, the left bound of the query falls in a hole between two intervals, so we have to check the right bound of the query; the (even-indexed) element that was found by `upper_bound` is the left bound of the next interval: if it's less than the right bound of the query, then we have an intersection, otherwise the query interval falls fully inside the hole, so there's no intersection.

Comment: Interesting.  But I don't quite understand what you mean by flattening into a single sequence.

Comment: @Robinson instead of having a list of pairs, each representing an interval, you flatten it into a left/right bounds; {{1, 3}, {5, 9}, {11, 27}}, for example, becomes {1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 27}. Even indexes are left bounds, odd indexes are right bounds. Flattening the intervals like this allows for easier handling as described in the answer.

Comment: The question asks for the first interval that intersects, not just if it intersects. You are changing the input data, not just the data structure, and can only answer if it intersects but no longer which of the original intervals intersected.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow the actual request was adjusted in the comments. OP needs to quickly know if there's an intersection, and can fall back to a slower algorithm to see what exact interval matches. Also, this approach can be tweaked (each merged interval can contain the range of original merged intervals to speed up the deeper search).

Comment: But, thinking about it more: if one cares only about the first matching interval, instead of a merge pass one may do a pass that removes the overlaps, i.e. if one has {2, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 7}, {4, 9} a single pass can actually transform all these intervals to non-overlapping {2, 5}, {5, 7}, {7, 9}, keeping only the non-overlapping parts and dropping the useless interval (possibly keeping an auxiliary value to refer back to the original intervals). Now you can apply the algorithm as-is and find the relevant interval.

Answer (score 1):

With the given input there is no way around checking every interval (worst case).

But if you have lots and lots of queries you can process the input once to make query faster.

First create

```
struct Interval {
    int start, end;
    size_t first_index;
};
std::vector<Interval> intervals;
```

then fill that from the input intervals, modifying each interval so there are no overlaps.

Say you have `(1, 4)` and `(3, 6)` then first you add `{1, 4, 0}` and then `{4, 6, 1}`. The part where the intervals overlap `(3, 4)` the query needs to return the first interval so you clip away that part from the second.

This process takes `O(n)` time but after that you can use binary search to find intervals. So it's only faster amortized over many queries.